# How do I get it to not to delete the rest of the dict

Tags: python, json, chatbot

I'm trying to create a .json from scratch, but I'm having some problems as you can see in the code below.

```
import json

storedata = {'intents' : []}

while True:
    word = input("Enter a new word.: ")
    if word.lower() == "exit":
       break
    else:
        word2 = input("Enter with an answer for the word: ")
        if bool(storedata['intents']):
            storedata['intents'].append({
                      'tag': 'New',
                      'patterns':[word],
                      'responses':[word2],
                      'context_set':''
                      })
        else:
            #storedata.update('intents').append({
             #         ['patterns']:[word],
              #        ['responses']:[word2]
               #       })years_dict[line[0]].append(line[1])
             #storedata('patterns',[]).append(word)
             storedata.setdefault('patterns',[]).append(word)
             storedata.setdefault('responses',[]).append(word2)
             #storedata.get('intents').update('responses', word2)
          #print("2")d.setdefault(year, []).append(value)

with open('storedata.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(storedata, outfile, indent=2)
```

What I want to create is exactly this.

```
{
  "intents": [],
  "tag": "New",
  "patterns": [
    "aaaa",
    "www"
  ],
  "responses": [
    "qqq",
    "eee"
  ],
  "context_set": ""
}
```

But what I've achieved so far is this

```
{
  "intents": [],
  "patterns": [
    "aaa",
    "qqq"
  ],
  "responses": [
    "www",
    "sss"
  ]
}
```

He erases the tag and context_set. My question is I add before or try to do something with the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your 'intent' is an empty list, therefore, it is not going into if block and hence you are not getting 'tag' and 'context_set' in output. Try this:

```
while True:
    word = input("Enter a new word.: ")
    if word.lower() == "exit":
       break
    else:
        word2 = input("Enter with an answer for the word: ")
        if bool(storedata['intents']):
            storedata['intents'].append({
                      'tag': 'New',
                      'patterns':[word],
                      'responses':[word2],
                      'context_set':''
                      })
        else:
            #storedata.update('intents').append({
             #         ['patterns']:[word],
              #        ['responses']:[word2]
               #       })years_dict[line[0]].append(line[1])
             #storedata('patterns',[]).append(word)
            storedata.setdefault('tag','New')
            storedata.setdefault('patterns',[]).append(word)
            storedata.setdefault('responses',[]).append(word2)
            storedata.setdefault('context_set','')
             #storedata.get('intents').update('responses', word2)
          #print("2")d.setdefault(year, []).append(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

it may be easier to store the data in a list and `json.dump` it into a text file, then read it as a list, that way you can see if its being stored and not read or not stored at all, it also tends to work better.

If not you could always create a code that adds tag and `context_set` after you get it, also try changing the `indent=2`, sometimes it can cause an error for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have spotted the reason for the behavior you are experiencing.

Walking through your code, you start off with `storeData = {'intents':[]}`

Next, the if-block, that starts with `if bool(storeData['intents']`, never gets executed since `bool(storeData['intents']` breaks down to `bool([])`, which is`False`.

Furthermore, you never really set the `"tag"` and `"context_set"` on `storeData` directly.

You only try to append to `storeData["intents"]` list in the afore-mentioned if-block (which again will never be reached).

I hope this helps to bring some clarity.

If you can set meaningful defaults for `"context_set"` or `"tag"` when initializing `storeData`, I would do so, especially if stuff breaks elsewhere in the absence of those keys.

Furthermore, double-check your logic to make sure that they are set to something when necessary, and at the right spot inside of `storeData`!

Answer (score 0):

I have done some changes to the code

```
if bool(storedata['intents']):
            storedata.update({'patterns':[word],'responses':[word2]})
            print("1")
            #storedata.setdefault('patterns',[]).append(word)
            #storedata.setdefault('responses',[]).append(word2)
        else:
            storedata['intents'].append({
                      'tag': 'New',
                      'patterns':[word],
                      'responses':[word2],
                      'context_set':''
                      })
            print("2")
```

now the data output is like this

```
{
  "intents": [
    {
      "tag": "New",
      "patterns": [
        "aaa"
      ],
      "responses": [
        "qqq"
      ],
      "context_set": ""
    }
  ],
  "patterns": [
    "eee"
  ],
  "responses": [
    "sss"
  ]
}
```

Even in setdefault the output looks like this.

I've already solved my problem after I searched here on the stack

```
        if bool(storedata['intents']):
            for intent in storedata["intents"]:
                for pattern in intent["patterns"]:
                    if extend1:
                        intent["patterns"].append(word)
                        extend1 = False
            for intent in storedata["intents"]:
                for pattern in intent["responses"]:
                    if extend2:
                        intent["responses"].append(word2)
                        extend2 = False
        else:
            storedata['intents'].append({
                      'tag': 'New',
                      'patterns':[word],
                      'responses':[word2],
                      'context_set':''
                      })
```